# Connect-AzAccount Stopped working. Fallback context save mode to process because of error during checking token

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am recording data to the Azure Storage account from time to time and today, the login command stopped working.
There were no changes to the service principal or permissions.

Here is an error.

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
WARNING: INITIALIZATION: Fallback context save mode to process because of error during checking token cache persistence: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Identity.Cli
ent.Extensions.Msal.StorageCreationPropertiesBuilder..ctor(System.String, System.String)'..
Connect-AzAccount : ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder 
Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.WithAzureRegion(System.String)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], AuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

I can't find a solution how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, there may be an issue with the `Microsoft Identity client library` and I can see in the error it is showing "Method not found". It means that there might be a missing method which is needed for authentication. That is why the authentication is failing.

***Need to check & resolve:***

- Update the module **"Microsoft.Identity.Client"**. Because updating the module will install & update all the required methods with the latest versions.

```
Update-Module Microsoft.Identity.Client
```

- If it is not working, then uninstall the module and reinstall it.

```
Uninstall-Module Microsoft.Identity.Client
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Identity.Client -RequiredVersion 4.32.1
```

[image]

- Run below command to clear the Azure PowerShell cache:

  ```
    Clear-AzContext -Force
  ```

After checking the above steps, I tried to `connect-Azaccount` with the service principal and it worked as expected.

```
 $Credential = Get-credential 
 connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId <TenantID> -Credential $Credential
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Jahnavi,

I did everything you said, but I still get the same error: 

Connect-AzAccount : ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder 
Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.WithAzureRegion(System.String)'

Comment: Can you register a new application and new secret and then give it a try! @OlegKazanskyi

Comment: I created a new app with a new secret and got the same error. 
Connecting with personal credentials using `Connect-AzAccount` works ok.

Comment: Did you check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-9.5.0)! @OlegKazanskyi

Comment: yes I did.
The same connection works on the cloud flow with no issues. It's relevant to something with my machine, I can't figure out what.

Comment: As you said, there might be your system issue. The same is working for me. If still the issue persists, contact Microsoft support. @OlegKazanskyi